# SQL pull data for the past two years

Tags: sql, plsql

How can I pull data from my table for just the past two years?

Current attempt which isn't recognizing "DATEADD":

```
select * 
from TABLE 
where EVENTDATE >= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Oracle and 2 years as 730 days you can do as simple as:

```sql
select *
  from table_name 
  where eventdate >= sysdate -730
;
```

When you add or subtract numbers from dates, oracle interpret the numbers as days.

Be aware that `date` is actually a date-time type and `sysdate` returns the current date-time. So if you are executing this query now at 10 pm it won't get the rows at 9 pm 2 years ago. Only the rows that are 10 pm or later.

You can remove (actually zero) the time of a `date` type doing `trunc(sysdate) -730`.

Also, the `trunc` function has more options. [See the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm).

Comment: Two years is not 720 days, or 730 days for that matter... :)

Comment: Fixed to 730 days! I assumed 730 days because the asker said it in a comment to another answer.

Answer (score 6):

PL/SQL suggests Oracle.  The correct logic is:

```
where eventdate >= sysdate - interval '2' year
```

Oracle can be finicky about interval arithmetic in general, `add_months()` is a good habit:

```
where eventdate >= add_months(sysdate, -24)
```

Of course, it depends what you mean by "2 year".  If you mean since Jan 1st of the last calendar year:

```
where eventdate >= trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') - interval '1' year
```

There is no problem when subtracting a year from January 1st.

Comment: Not recognizing "DATEADD"  (or "GETDATE" for that matter) because they are NOT an Oracle nor a SQL standard functions. Those are strictly(?) MS sql server functions .

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Belayer

Comment: @GordonLinoff I basically want the past 730 days, does the first example do that?

Comment: @SebastianHubard . . . You can use `- interval '730' day` if that is what you want. –

Comment: Need to be careful with `sysdate - interval '2' year`, it will fail with an exception on a leap day.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp . . . I modified the answer to offer `add_months()` as an alternative.  However, there is no issue subtracting "1 year" from Jan 1st.  Leap years do not play into that.  Note that `trunc()`.

Comment: Correct - the issue only happens for the first example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ADD_MONTHS function to compare to a valid date, 2 years in the past:

```
select * 
from TABLE 
where EVENTDATE >= ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -24)
```

Note: `sysdate - interval '2' year` will not yield a valid date on leap days (will raise exception ORA-01839), but ADD_MONTHS will give a valid date each time.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is ugly but will do the  job for you :)

```
select *
  from TABLE
 where EVENTDATE >= TO_DATE(to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') - 1 || '-' || to_char(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: This will fail on a leap day.